# Separate array of elements by attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Let's say I've got a form with several inputs, and I use a pretty standard jQuery statement to get them all:

```
var inputs = $("#some-form").find("input")
```

Now, I'd like to act on those inputs, but let's say I want to treat the radio button and/or checkbox groups as a single thing.  How can I split `inputs` out into elements grouped by an attribute, say `name`.  Note, that I don't know what the name is going to be when the processing starts.

In human terms, I need the logic do do something along the lines of:

> Let me iterate over the list of inputs.  For each input, let me check
>   to see if it's already been added to a placeholder array.  If so,
>   leave it alone. If not, add it and everything with it's name to said
>   placeholder array (as a sub array).

Essentially, I'd like something like this:

```
[[<input type="text" name="name1">], [<input type="radio" name="name2">,<input type="radio" name="name2">]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getInputsPartitioned(formEl) {
    var inputEls = formEl.querySelectorAll("input");

    var inputsByName = Object.create(null);
    for (var i = 0; i < inputEls.length; ++i) {
        var inputEl = inputEls[i];
        var name = inputEl.name;

        if (!(name in inputsByName)) {
            inputsByName[name] = [];
        }
        inputsByName[name].push(inputEl);
    }

    // `inputsByName` now looks like this:
    // {
    //     name1: [<input type="text" name="name1">],
    //     name2: [<input type="radio" name="name2">, <input type="radio" name="name2">]
    // }

    // To get it into arrays:

    return Object.keys(inputsByName).map(function (name) {
        return inputsByName[name];
    });
}
```

Bonus: no jQuery needed.

Answer (score 2):

Try using attribute selector inside a filter.

```
var $formInput = $('#some-form').find('input');
var inputText = $formInput.filter('[type=text]')
var otherInput = $formInput.filter("[type=radio]")
                          .add($formInput.filter('[type=checkbox]'));
```

or even better

```
var otherInput = $formInput.filter(function () {
                     return this.type == 'radio' || this.type == 'checkbox';
                  });
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/utwaf/

> How can I split inputs out into elements grouped by an attribute, say name

```
var elements = []; //elements by name
var $formInput = $('#some-form').find('input');
elements.push($formInput.filter(function() { 
   return this.name == 'name1';
});
elements.push($formInput.filter(function() { 
   return this.name == 'name2';
});
```

**Note:** All elements pushed into the array are jQuery objects.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified.  I don't know the name of the input when I start the processing.  Basically, I want to be able to have the code say "Ok, I've got an input. Check to make sure I haven't already added it to the array of inputs, and if not, add it and everything with the same name to the array."